# Javascript erase image with cursor

Tags: javascript, cursor, erase

Is it possible with javascript?

I'm trying to implement a scratchcard type thing, and I was wondering if the user could 'scratch it' with his cursor and then javascript would remove/erase the image to show the text below.

But i've not been able to find anything (javascript wise) which can erase abit (cursor location) of an image.

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Also if there's a HTML5 alternative please tell me :)

Comment: Something knocked up in canvas would be your best bet for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use html5 canvas element.

Checkout this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/WUXDb/1/

Comment: Is it possible to do this for mobile users too, using `touchmove`?

Comment: @Justin yes it is, you just need to rename the `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` and `onmousemove` events to the corresponding touch event handlers, and change the `onmousemove` method a bit, since the touch coordinates are handled a bit differently (http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#the-touchmove-event)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Plugin: http://www.senamion.com/blog/jScratchcard.html

HTML5: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2011/06/28/a-jquery-canvas-scratch-off/