# Have you give a lottery scratch effect in css3?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I will need your help
I will try to run immediately in css3 animation features demo view.

***[demo view!!](http://wscratchpad.websanova.com/)***

Example source

http://jsfiddle.net/cyh123123/myndwLn0/embedded/result/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/cyh123123/myndwLn0/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please show us whatever code you have tried till now mate.

Comment: Is this your code http://jsfiddle.net/cyh123123/myndwLn0/

Comment: Try this it's not really mine http://jsfiddle.net/WUXDb/394/
for more check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903404/javascript-erase-image-with-cursor

Answer (score 2):

Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/myndwLn0/2/

it's really hard i added a lot of these divs and it works on hover you can also change the cursor 
You can make the 'block's smaller for a better view

so that it covers the image an the added the css

```
.block{
background-color:green;
width:80px;
height:48px;
position:relative;
float:left;
z-index:10;

 transition:0s 100s;
}

.block:hover{
 transition:0s;
 z-index:-10;
}
```